# What is top arrow mean in Xcdoe branch section on merged branches?

Tags: xcode, git

When I push and merge some branch to master or any branch to another branch I see a number with a top arrow next to the merged branch. What's this mean?

[image: xcode branch > arrow top]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it, It's number of ahead commits from remote branch.